# Update query from two tables, but some exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

[Picture(screen shot) http://test.englisheye.co.kr/pic44.jpg](http://test.englisheye.co.kr/pic44.jpg)

Please look at the picture above.

I need to update `Table_B` from `Table_A` with a T-SQL query.
(Ordinary update with two tables doesn't work here.)

The question is the values like `'4,7'` or `'5,3'`.

I think I need to create a function, but don't know where to start.

Please help me.

Comment: Post your query in question. Image is not accessible.

Comment: I corrected image URL. Now it should be accessible. Please refer to the image. It's quite a special case, so we need to see the image.

Comment: can num column in Table_B hold more then 2 numbers?

Comment: `I think I need to create a function, but don't know where to start` – I would start with a simpler problem. Your question contains at least two major issues to resolve: 1) split a CSV string into separate values, and 2) concatenate separate values into a CSV string. And if you've never created functions before, that would be a third one. So, start solving those independently. Search for ready solutions, try to understand them, then try to apply them to your situation. When you've got a *specific* issue, please feel free to come back here and ask about it. So far I'm voting this as Unclear.

Comment: After doing some research, I think I can work with 'CURSOR'. Thank you guys!~ I'll find my way through this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a int, @b nvarchar (20),@c nvarchar (20),@f nvarchar (20),@d int,@e int=1,@g nvarchar(20)
set @b='' set  @c='' set @d =1 set  @f='';

create table #mytable (num nvarchar (20),start nvarchar (20) ,[end] nvarchar (20))

while @e<=(select count(*)from table_b) begin
set @a= (SELECT (len (num)+1)/2 FROM (select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by [start]) as id, * from table_b) a  where id=@e)
while @d<=@a begin
set @b =(SELECT  SUBSTRING(num,2*@d-1,1) FROM (select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by start) as id, * from table_b) a  where id=@e)
set @c +=(select [end] from Table_A where num =cast (@b as int)) +', '
set @f +=(select [end] from Table_A where num =cast (@b as int)) +', '
set @d+=1
end
set @g = ( select num from (select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by [start]) as id, * from table_b) w  where id=@e)
insert into #mytable
select @g, left(@c,case when len(@c)>1 then len(@c)-1  else len(@c) end ) as 'c',
left(@f,case when len(@f)>1 then len(@f)-1  else len(@f) end ) as 'f'

set @b='' set  @c='' set @d =1 set  @f=''
set @e+=1
end

update b 
set b.start =t.start, b.[end]=t.[end] 
from Table_B b
inner join #mytable t on b.num =t.num
drop table #mytable
```

It's a bit complex code but works for me.